# Directly send Screenshot without saving

Tags: macos, screen-capture

We are using Skype for Business in our company, sometimes there failures or errors we need to send to another employee.

Is there a simple way to directly send a screenshot after creating it without saving it on the SSD of the Mac?

Comment: not without creating Automator action and telling it where and to whom to send it

Comment: Besides using system tools, there's a plethora of free screenshot software that will upload a screenshot or a screen recording directly to the cloud and automatically put a link in your clipboard.

I use a service like this myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can also copy to clipboard with

- <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for the whole screen
- <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> for a part of the screen
- <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> followed by <kbd>space</kbd> for a single window

and then paste the screenshot in a messaging application. As far as I see Skype for Business does not allow images in the chat. So you will have to use email or some other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the Folder your screenshots are saved.

Select `Folder Action Setup`

a new window opens click on `Edit Workflow`

a new widow opens

set it up as following

[image]

Now when you take a new screenshot it will be automatically emailed to your specified person/email.

> Save that

PS it will be also saved on your computer at same time, but if you want it deleted we can do that.

Comment: Works fine with Mail but not with Skype for Buisness.

Comment: @FabianGr Sadly Skype for Business does not support images in the chat. You will have to attach a file or choose another way to send the screenshots.

Comment: @FabianGr Maybe I missed it. How do you take the screenshot ?

Comment: I use the System Commands for taking screenshots like command+control+shift+4

Comment: @FabianGr then my suggestion should work for you, the person you are sending it to will get it (by mail) unless you insist to send it via Skype